# Rails/Javascript: Data attribute not returned through partial, but present in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to display the value of a select field for shipping costs beneath the field. Thanks to @Vasfed I am tying to use data attributes and javascript. But while the data attribute is rendered in the DOM while loading th page it is not returned in the data returned for the AJAX call when inspecting console or resources.

In DOM:

```
<select id="shippingservices_select" name="cart[shippingservice_id]"><option value="">select a carrier</option>
  <option value="7" data-price="3.9">UPS</option>
  <option value="19" data-price="10.0">DHL</option>
</select>
```

The fetched partial:

```
$("#shippingservices_select").empty()
  .append("<option value=\"7\">UPS<\/option><option value=\"19\">DHL<\/option>");
```

I am using the following ajax call:

```
$(document).on("change", "#lands_select", function(event){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/carts/update_shipping/" + event.target.value,
    type: "GET",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Which should return both value and data attribute, for the form:

```
<%= form_for :cart, :url => {:action => "show_shipping"}, :html => { :method => "get", :remote => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:land_id, Land.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "select a country"}, {:id => 'lands_select'}) %><br>
  <%= f.select(:shippingservice_id, options_for_select(@shippingservices.collect { |s| [s.name.titleize, s.id, {'data-price' => s.price}] }), {:prompt => "select a carrier"}, {:id => 'shippingservices_select'}) %><br>
<% end %>
Shipping: €<div id="shipping_cost"></div><br>
```

with the update_shipping.js.erb view:

```
$("#shippingservices_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @shippingservices)) %>");
```

and the rendered partial _shippingservice.html.erb of:

```
<option value="<%= shippingservice.id %>" data-price="<%= shippingservice.price %>"><%= shippingservice.name.titleize %></option>
```

In the controller I have:

```
def update_shipping
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Following my partial _shippingservice.html.erb I should get both value and data attribute, but I do not. I think this is the reason why:

```
$(document).on("change", "#shippingservices_select", function(event){
  var price = $(event.target).data('price');
  $("#shipping_cost").html(price);
});
```

Does not return the value of data-price.

How can I get this to work? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I was trying to troubleshoot it and things appear to be quite strange.

Both selectors display data in the DOM. The shipping service select field which get’s loaded on page load shows everything. On changing the land selector, the partial which gets loaded and which I can inspect in console does only display option value + name, but when changing the _shippingservice partial I found out that the code which gets loaded through AJAX appears not to be generated by the partial referenced in the JS Ajax call, since I can change the code inside without producing any effect on the delivered payload.

But when substituting

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @shippingservices))%>
```

By

```
<%= escape_javascript(render ‘carts/shippingservice’)%>
```

Nothing is displayed and loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what partials are getting rendered on the terminal where you are running rails. Looks like you have more than 1 possible partial for shipping services.

You can also specify which partial to use instead of letting rails guess:

```
render partial: 'carts/shippingservice', collection: @shippingservices, as: :shippingservice
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking that the call might be the problem, that a variable would be too loose. I was not aware of the options you suggested. Is there any documentation where I can educate myself about this? Thanks again.